# Space filling curve as parametrization of the plane

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, surfaces

I was introduced to space filling curves recently and it occurred to me that it seems you could use them to parametrize any surface in $\mathbb R^3$ using only one real parameter, which is as far as I know not possible.

From what I understand, a space filling curve such as the Hilbert curve is a homoemorphism between the real line and a subset of the plane. Since a composition of homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism, we could compose the surface patch(es) of say a sphere with the Hilbert curve to get a homeomorphism between the real line and the sphere. But this is impossible since the sphere is a 2-manifold. Any guidance as to where I go wrong would be much appreciated!

I have to say I was only introduced to the Hilbert curve informally so this is probably the root of my confusion.

Comment: First of all, while you could say that it is a parametrization, a space filling curve can't be differentiable. Also, if you take a subinterval of the domain and look at what you get in $\mathbb R^2$, it will be indescribably horrible.

Comment: @MattSamuel I actually thought about this, however even if in practice we would want to parametrize surfaces smoothly, this is more of a fundamental question. I thought by nature the sphere (for example) could *only* be described using two parameters. This seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: You certainly can cover a sphere with a space filling curve, but it's not a useful parametrization.

Comment: @MattSamuel wouldn't this mean though that the sphere is then homeomorphic to the line, i.e. that the sphere is a 1-manifold?

Comment: A space-filling curve is not injective. Hence not a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you for that! I was under the impression that the Hilbert curve was in fat injective. Things make more sense now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally: any injective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is always a homeomorphism from the domain to the range. Hence, any injective map from a close interval to a plane will look exactly like a curve, 1-dimensional and barely capable of filling anything. Space filling curve is not injective.

Comment: You may be overeaching a bit. The range of such a map can have positive area.